# How do I capture data with submit for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the background and color of a text with 2 different forms when clicking the submit button of the same form I have this code and already can change the text.

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'A') {
    $("h1").css('background-color', 'white');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'B') {
    $("h1").css('background-color', 'red');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'C') {
    $("h1").css('background-color', 'yellow');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'D') {
    $("h1").css('background-color', 'green');
  }
});

$('#select1').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'A') {
    $("h1").css('color', 'white');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'B') {
    $("h1").css('color', 'red');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'C') {
    $("h1").css('color', 'yellow');
  }
  if ($(this).val() == 'D') {
    $("h1").css('color', 'green');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
    H1 TEXT TO CHANGE
    </h1>
<h3>
    Background Text
    </h3>
<form method="POST">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="A">White</option>
    <option value="B">Red</option>
    <option value="C">Yellow</option>
    <option value="D">Green</option>
  </select>
  <h3>
    Color Text
    </h3>

  <select id="select1">
    <option value="A">White</option>
    <option value="B">Red</option>
    <option value="C">Yellow</option>
    <option value="D">Green</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>

</form>
```

When I add a function linked with the submit button I get error.

```
<button onclick="capture()">Change</button>

function capture(){
*Actual JS*
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? On submit you'll get transfered to another page, you won't see the change

Comment: Only change to the selected color by clicking on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your form with an ID for simplicity:

```
<form id="form-id">
...
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#form-id').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
  // some more JS
});
```

VanillaJS:

```
document.getElementById('form-id').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  // some more JS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function and `ColorText` id to your h3 tag ;)

```
function capture(){
  var e = document.getElementById("select");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  var e2 = document.getElementById("select1");
  var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor=strUser;
  document.getElementById("ColorText").style.color=strUser2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID on the button:

```
<button id="submit">Change</button>
```

And an event listener where you can retrieve the choice and apply corresponding css:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    // prevent the form from actually submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    var choices = {
        "A": "white",
        "B": "red",
        "C": "yellow",
        "D": "green"
    };

    var choiceBG = $("#select").val();
    $("h1").css('background-color', choices[choiceBG]);

    var choiceFG = $("#select1").val();
    $("h1").css('color', choices[choiceFG]);
});
```